# Weka java accuracy different compared to weka explorer

Tags: java, api, weka, explorer

I am working with weka's java api and I am tyring to find accuracy with J48.

```
    J48 J48_classifier = new new J48();
    J48_classifier.buildClassifier(data);   // build classifier
    eval.crossValidateModel(J48_classifier, data, 10, new Random(1));
    System.out.println(eval.pctCorrect());
```

I am getting 76% accuracy with using the Java API. Though when I use explorer I get 99% accuracy that is a large difference.

What could I be doing wrong I hear its the random value produced for the java but its noticeable for a lot of the other classifiers as well. I don't know where to start or has anybody else dealt with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out what you need to do is build your own cross-validation for java this can be done by the examples provided by weka. The link is below it was able to give me the same results as the explorer.

https://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+%28Java+approach%29

This only works for classifier-based recognition, not clustering.